# Hyperparameter Tuning vs Regularization

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, hyperparameter-tuning, regularization

While designing the architecture of a Neural Network, should I consider adding regularization (like Dropout, L1/L2, etc.) even after optimizing the problem using Hyperparameter Tuning? What should be the main focus (tuning or regularization) to achieve more generalization, considering that both of these simplify the problem?

P.S.: Links to some recent publications would be of great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is **generally recommended to use regularization techniques**, such as **Dropout, L1/L2 regularization**, etc., ***even after optimizing the problem using hyperparameter tuning***. **Regularization** techniques help to prevent overfitting by adding constraints to the model and simplifying the model complexity, which can improve the generalization performance.

On the other hand, **hyperparameter tuning** optimizes the hyperparameters of the model to find the best configuration that minimizes the error on the training set.

In summary, both **hyperparameter tuning** and **regularization** are important ***for achieving more generalization*** in a neural network. **Hyperparameter tuning** helps to find the optimal values for the hyperparameters of the model, such as the learning rate, the number of hidden layers, etc., which can improve the performance of the model. **Regularization** techniques, on the other hand, help to reduce the complexity of the model and prevent overfitting, which can also improve the generalization performance of the model.

Therefore, it is ***recommended to use both hyperparameter tuning and regularization techniques to achieve more generalization*** in a neural network.

Here are some recent **publications** that discuss the **use of regularization** and **hyperparameter tuning** for Neural Networks:

- [**Understanding Regularization in Deep Learning**](https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.08741) by **B. Zoph and Q. V. Le**
- [**Hyperparameter Optimization for Neural Networks: A Survey**](https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.07623) by **A. K. Agarwal, S. R. M. Prasad, and A. R. Menon**
- [**Dropout: A Simple Way to Prevent Neural Networks from Overfitting**](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/%7Ehinton/absps/JMLRdropout.pdf) by **N. Srivastava, G. Hinton, A. Krizhevsky, I. Sutskever, and R. Salakhutdinov**
- [**Early Stopping - But When?**](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.5555/2969239.2969312) by **Y. Lecun, L. Bottou, Y. Bengio, and P. Haffner**
- **[Reducing Overfitting In Neural Networks by Constraining the Complexity of the Model](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1705.07832.pdf)** by **Yarin Gal and Zoubin Ghahramani**
- **[An Overview of Regularization Techniques in Deep Learning](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1701.05369.pdf)** by **Danilo Jimenez Rezende and Shakir Mohamed**

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot!!!